# A suspended transaction release the "select for update" lock?

Tags: spring, transactions, locking

```
Transaction A(PROPAGATION_REQUIRED) {

   lock = "select * from lock_table while id = 1 for update"      
   Method son(){
       Transaction B(PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW){}         
   }
}
```

I know that PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW will suspend the current transaction (if one exists) and start a new one, which means Transaction A will be suspended.

**But would Transaction A release the "select for update" lock when it is  suspended? Could other thread get the lock when Transaction A is suspended?**

Thank You!